# How can I make a dot nation on a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

How can I make a dot notation on a function, I mean like in jQuery's function.
Example:

```
func("test_string").func2("test_string2");
```

Comment: you return an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply return an object from the first funtion which itself has a function

```js
function func(input){
  console.log("You called func with: " + input);
  return {
     func2: function(x){
         console.log("You called func2 with: " + x);
     }
  }
}


func("test_string").func2("test_string2");
```

Answer (score 1):

You're effectively invoke method on `func`'s return value, so just make the return value (an object that) contains a member function `func2`.

```js
function func(str){
  return { //return an object with func2
    func2(str2){console.log(`${str} ${str2}`);}
  }
}

func("test_string").func2("test_string2");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery either returns jQuery or it returns an object with methods.  So if you wanted some function that would console log and return itself you could do something like this:

```js
const myObj = {
  logit: (str) => {
    console.log(str);
    return myObj;
  }
}



myObj.logit('hello').logit('world');
```

Answer (score 0):

to make benefits of method chaining, you should have a base object that has multiple methods, and you should return the actual reference of the object in every method, so let's say you have a User object that looks like :

```
class User {
  constructor(...args){
    // object construction goes here
  }
 func(...args){
  // Methods logic goes here
  // Here we should return the actual object (instance of User class)
  // which is referred by this
  return this;
 }
 func2(...args){
  // We do the same here 
  return this;
 }
}

// We create an instance of User
const user = new User();

// Now we can chain our methods since each method return our object
user.func(args).func2(args);
```